# Remove port number from URL

Tags: magento-1.8, url

Is it possible to remove the port number from the url? I.e., I access the website by `mywebsite.com` but when I click something else in the page, it adds `:8080` right between the domain name and the current page, so it will be smth like `mywebsite.com:8080/flags`. and I want to just hide this port number part from the URL.

After some research I could only find tutorials and help about removing or changing ports or redirections, etc.

Maybe it is possible somewhere from the admin panel?

**UPDATE:**

I found out that I have to set `port_in_redirect` to `off`, in some server block, which is...? ([info here](http://www.nude-webdesign.com/fix-port-in-url-with-nginx-varnish-cache/#respond))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `System->Configuration->Web->Unsecure` and check the values for `Base URL` and `Base Link URL`. remove any trace of `:8080` that you find in there.

Do the same for the `Secure` section.